Examples of Serre duality for $L^2$-cohomology with compact support for holomorphic vector bundles on non-compact complex manifolds?
It is well-known that the cohomology $H^*(X,E)$ with values in a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ on a compact complex manifold $X$ can be computed with harmonic differential forms with respect to suitable Hermitian metrics. As a consequence one obtains a proof of Serre's duality theorem.
On a non-compact complex manifold $X$ one introduces a Hilbert space structure on the $L^2$-cohomology. One obtains a Serre duality theorem for the $L^2$-cohomology on $X$ if the $\overline{\partial}$-operators have closed image, see “Chakrabarti and Shaw: $L^2$ Serre duality on domains in complex manifolds and applications. Transact. of the AMS, Vol. 364 , No. 7 July 2012”
My question:

Which non-compact complex manifolds $X$ are typical examples having $\overline{\partial}$-operators with closed image?

In particular, what about a non-compact irreducible Hermitian symmetric space $X$, embedded via the Harish-Chandra embedding as an open subset of its dual $X^*$, a compact Hermitian symmetric space?
